# PDF and CDF of the ratio of the max to min of an iid random sample: a quick check of the calculation!

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

My question can be thought as a direct continuation of [this important question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2631988/find-joint-distribution-of-minimum-and-maximum-of-iid-random-variables) and its first answer (but see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054665/joint-distribution-of-minx-1-ldots-x-n-and-maxx-1-ldots-x-n?noredirect=1&lq=1) also), which gives us the joint distribution of the max and min of an iid random sample. In my question, I just wanted to *make sure* if this formula for the ratio  of maximum to minimum of an iid random sample is correct, given that first answer to the abovementioned question, which is indeed correct.

**Proposition:** Let $\{N_1 \dots N_n\}$ be iid random sample generated by a *positive* random variable $N > 0$ with CDF $F_N$ and PDF $f_N.$ Let $U_n, L_n$ denote the maximum and minimum of the random sample. Let us denote the PDF of their joint distribution by $f_{U_n, L_n}$ and  that of the ratio by  $f_{\frac{U_n}{L_n}}. $ Then we have the following expression of the PDF of the ratio:

$$  f_{\frac{U_n}{L_n}}(z) =  n(n-1)\int_{s=0}^{\infty}sf_N(s)f_N(sz)(F_N(sz)-F_N(s))^{n-2}, z \in [1, \infty) $$

Note that: $\frac{U_n}{L_n} \ge 1.$ So let $ z \ge  1.$ Then:
\begin{align*}
 \\& f_{\frac{U_n}{L_n}}(z)
 \\& = \frac{d}{dz} P[\frac{U_n}{L_n} \le z]
 \\&= \frac{d}{dz} P[{U_n} \le z L_n]
 \\&= \frac{d}{dz} \int_{ \{ t \le z s\} } f_{L_n, U_n}(s,t) ds dt
 \\&= \frac{d}{dz} \int_{s=0}^{\infty} \left[  \int_{t=0}^{zs} f_{L_n, U_n}(s,t) ds  \right]  dt
 \\&=  \int_{s=0}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dz} \left[  \int_{t=0}^{zs} f_{L_n, U_n}(s,t)  ds \right]  dt
 \\&=  \int_{s=0}^{\infty} s  f_{L_n, U_n}(s,sz) ds
 \\&= n(n-1) \int_{s=0}^{\infty} s f_N(s)f_N(sz)(F_N(sz)-F_N(s))^{n-2} ds
    \\& \text{ (The next step is only for Uniform distributions) }
    \\&= n(n-1) \int_{s=0}^{1/z} s f_N(s)f_N(sz)(F_N(sz)-F_N(s))^{n-2} ds (\text{ because when } sz > 1, f_N(sz)=0. )
 \end{align*}

Note that in the second to last line of the above, proof, I indeed used the general (*not* for *uniform* distribution) expression for $f_{L_n, U_n}$ provided by the first answer to the question I mentioned in the very first line. In the last line, we specialized for uniform distributions.

**EDIT:** After a few first comments, I'm including a check for $n=2, N \sim \mathcal{U}(0,1)$ below:

Plug in $n=2, $ and assume $N \sim U(0,1),$ then the last line of my calculation becomes $2 \int_{0}^{1/z}sds= 1/z^2,$ which is the PDF of the [inverse uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution#Inverse_uniform_distribution). Now note that, in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2954557/ratio-distribution-of-max-and-min-for-uniform-random-variables), they treat the distribution of $L_2/U_2$ and obtain it as a uniform distribution $\mathcal{U}(0,1),$ implying that at least in this simple case, my calculations are correct.

Indeed a similar calculation also shows that when $X_i \sim_{i.i.d.} \mathcal{U}(0,1), U_n/L_n$ has PDF $f_{U_n/L_n}(z)= \frac{n-1}{z^n}, z \geq 1.$

Comment: Does you general result matches the $n=2$ particular case treated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2954557) with an especialy simple expression?

Comment: @JeanMarie I'll check - but in the link you cited, the author is asking for the reciprocal of what I'm asking: (s)he's asking for the distribution of $\frac{L_2}{U_2},$ not that of $\frac{U_2}{L_2},$ which is what I'm asking for.

Comment: @LearningMath easy enough to adapt the same argument to the inverse of the fraction, would it match?

Comment: @gt6989b It seems to match. If I plug in $n=2, $ and assume $N \sim U(0,1),$ then the last line of my calculation becomes $2 \int_{0}^{1/z}sds= 1/z^2,$ which is the PDF of the inverse uniform distribution - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution#Inverse_uniform_distribution.

Comment: Added it as an edit, thanks!

Comment: Distribution of $U_2/L_2$ for $U(0,1)$ is in fact derived [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/662630/321264).