# Find the distribution of $X=\frac{\max\{U,V\}}{\min\{U,V\}}$

Tags: probability

Suppose that $U,V$ are two independent uniform $(0,1)$ random variables. Find the distribution  of $X=\dfrac{\max\{U,V\}}{\min\{U,V\}}$.

Ok to find $\max(U,V)$ we have $P(\max(U,V)\leq r)=P(U\leq r)P(V \leq r)= r^2$ so $P(\max(U,V)=r)=2r$. I can do the same trick with $\min(u,v)$ but then I don't know how to deal with the fraction of the two?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$X$ and $Y$ are uniformly ditributed on $(0,1)$. distribution of $\max(X,Y)/\min(X,Y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662601/x-and-y-are-uniformly-ditributed-on-0-1-distribution-of-maxx-y-min)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

If you consider $(U,V)$ as a uniform distribution on a unit square,

then $\mathbb P\left(\dfrac{\max\{U,V\}}{\min\{U,V\}} \le x\right)$ involves find the area of the square less two congruent right-angled triangles